# Collect list of list using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following line stream that I read from a file

1      2   4.5

1 6  3     5.5   5.3   6

1  7.2     5     7

How can I collect these lines in a single list of list considering only the Integers? (Notice that within each line the numbers are separated by one or more white spaces)

This is what I tried, but this give me one single list of all integer elements.

```
        list = reader.lines()
            .map(m -> m.split("\\n"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .map(m -> m.split("\\s+"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(f -> !f.contains("."))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
reader.lines()
   .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))
                      .filter(f -> !f.contains("."))
                      .map(Integer::parseInt)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: You're right. lines() is self explanatory. It already return the lines one by one. And I didn't know I could create a new stream inside the map function. Got the strategy! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
list = reader.lines()
    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))
        .filter(number -> !number.contains("."))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may also want to filter for empty lines:

```
 list = reader.lines()
    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))
        .filter(number -> !number.contains("."))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .map(l -> !l.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```